# React re-rendering components issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I started my first real project in React, I'm developing a portfolio site and I have a strange issue when I use the category filter to switch the categories.

***The issue is:*** The site shows all the projects, if you click in Artwort or switch between the buttons you will see that not all the projects are showing the transition animation, it seems that the projects in the current category are not rendering again. Another weird thing is in the react developer tools the profiler shows how all the components are rendering when y change the category.

I think this behavior will have logical explanation, but I couldn't find it because I'm using useEffect dependency with the currentCat state.

you can see the error here: https://toiatemp-manuverrastro.vercel.app/

Here is the components:

```
https://github.com/manuverrastro/toia/blob/main/src/components/Filter.js
https://github.com/manuverrastro/toia/blob/main/src/components/Work.js
https://github.com/manuverrastro/toia/blob/main/src/components/WorkList.js
https://github.com/manuverrastro/toia/blob/main/src/components/WorkListContainer.js
```

Does anyone have some idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `key` property in your `WorkList.js` file. Although the categories are different, `work.id` is not getting changed while you switch between the tabs. Since you have given work.id as the key parameter React tries to render the same previous element without re-rendering it. Because of that you don't see any animation in those `Work` components.

You can change your `key` prop which is given to the `Work` component, by concatenating  the current selected category. So each time you switch between the tabs, `key` prop will differ. It will result in re-rendering the `Work` components. I have changed your code as my suggestion.

*WorkList.js*

```
import Work from "./Work";

const WorkList = ({ work, currentCat }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {currentCat
        ? work
            .filter((work) => work.category == currentCat)
            .map((work) => {
              return (
                <Work
                  key={`${currentCat}-${work.id}`}
                  id={work.id}
                  slug={work.slug}
                  thumbnail={work.thumbnail}
                  image={work.image}
                  title={work.title}
                  category={work.category}
                />
              );
            })
        : work.map((work) => {
            return (
              <Work
                key={`all-${work.id}`}
                id={work.id}
                slug={work.slug}
                thumbnail={work.thumbnail}
                image={work.image}
                title={work.title}
                category={work.category}
              />
            );
          })}
    </>
  );
};

export default WorkList;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I knew it had a logical explanation. I didn't imagine that the key property needs to change in this case to re-render a component.

The code works perfectly, I appreciate your time.